# pulseaudio doesn't work permanently

Tags: ubuntu, audio, pulseaudio

I use pulseaudio on Ubuntu.
After I start pulseaudio daemon using `pulseaudio --start` command, it starts working well.
But it doesn't work permanently. It turns off very soon.
So I have to retype `pulseaudio --start` every time I want to play music.

**Additional information**

When I check the list of processes related to pulseaudio, I find it working as a system daemon:

`$ps -alx | grep pulse`

~ UID ~ COMMAND

~ 108 ~ pulseaudio --system

~ 998 ~ pulseaudio --system

I can't understand why processes work as system in other user.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pulseaudio), the pulseaudio server can be started with the option `--exit-idle-time` that defines the time after which the daemon terminates when being idle. Setting this option with `-1` should keep the daemon alive.

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
systemctl --user enable pulseaudio && systemctl --user start pulseaudio
```